# Two paginations not working independently in one page - CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I have one web page and in this page I need total 2 paginations for different different 2 tables.

I have tried with different pagination but it's dependent with each other.

For ex., If I select second page of first table then second table automatically changed with 2nd page.

Here is my controller code code :

```
$page = $this->pageForPagination('User');
$this->paginate = array(
        'User' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'User.*',
            ),
            'conditions' => $userConditions,
            'page' => $page,
        ),
    );
 $this->set('users', $this->paginate('User'));

 $page1 = $this->pageForPagination('Game');
 $this->paginate = array(
        'Game' => array(
            'fields' => array(
                'Game.*',
            ),
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'page' => $page1,
        ),
    );
 $this->set('games', $this->paginate('Game'));
```

Here is the function that is used in above code :

```
function pageForPagination($model) {
    $page = 1;
    $sameModel = isset($this->params['named']['model']) && $this->params['named']['model'] == $model;
    $pageInUrl = isset($this->params['named']['page']);
    if ($sameModel && $pageInUrl) {
        $page = $this->params['named']['page'];
    }

    $this->passedArgs['page'] = $page;
    return $page;
}
```

Here is my view code :

```
echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'User'));
echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'Game'));
```

I have referred above code from this url : http://debuggable.com/posts/how-to-have-multiple-paginated-widgets-on-the-same-page-with-cakephp:48ad241e-b018-4532-a748-0ec74834cda3

Can any one help me because I didn't get any solution still?

Comment: Because they are sharing the same parameter. You need to use different parameters for different paginations.

Comment: Not getting your point.
Can you please advice with code?
Sorry but I'm new in CakePHP so..

Comment: How the action would know which model to paginate? Do you have any conditions? The query string parameters is same for both paginations I guess.

Comment: There is "model:XXX" in url.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the link you mentioned is to override the default pagination urls and doesn't display both models at the same time. You haven't implemented the solution completely.

You have to extract the page number manually for each model like this:

```
function pageForPagination($model) {
    if (isset($this->params['named']['pagefor'.$model])
        return $this->params['named']['pagefor'.$model];
    else
        return 1;
}
```

The code below:

```
echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'User'));
echo $this->element('paging', array('model' => 'Game'));
```

causes the cakephp to use the default pagination view and the urls in the default pagination are the same for both models. You have to use custom pagination view and specify the model for the page link.

For the edited function above you can use a url pattern like this:

```
/Controller/Action/pageforUser:215/pageforGame:35
```

for each page link in your view.

I think best practice to use this url pattern is to override the pagination helper so that the links that are created form the following pattern:

```
'/Controller/Action/pagefor[Model]:215'.[other parameters]
```

Comment: Hi @Alto,
How can I add pageFor in element page?
Can you please help me on it?

Comment: Yes @Alto can you please help me for that which question asked by Navin Nakum?

Comment: You can use simple <a> or $this->Html->link instead of cake default pagination elements such as next, previous etc to generate links containing pagination data for both models.

Comment: Hi @Alto, Thank you for your reply but I have already paging.ctp which will return pagination for both. like in my question posted URL.
I want to set the pageforUser and pageforGame in pagination of this.

Comment: I edited my answer and added the way you can change the pagination links at the bottom of each 'paging' element to set the pageforUser and pageforGame.